# Pass a property from an ItemsControl source class into a converter parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, ivalueconverter

I have an `ItemsControl` like this

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonInputControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <local:CustomTextBox
                        StringInTextBox="{Binding
                            Path=UIntProperty,
                            Mode=TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                            Converter={local:UIntConverter Param=123}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ToggleButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The source of the `ItemsControl` is set in code and it is an `ObservableCollection` of type `MyClass` which has a property named `UIntProperty`. The converter `UIntConverter` extends `MarkupExtension` so I can use it like above and has a  `uint` property called `Param`.

**Objective**

The objective is to edit `UIntProperty` using the `CustomTextBox`. If a no numeric value is typed, the value `UIntProperty` should not change and if the `StringInTextBox` is empty,
the value should be set to `0` and display that value. More conditions are required for a `float` type, but the case of a `uint` should give the idea of the final objective.

**I have tried**

I can use the dependency property `StringInTextBox` with the `CoerceValueCallback` and `PropertyChangedCallback`, but according to my test, the bindings trigger first, so the UIntConverter performs first and that is where the `UIntProperty` is set. I could use an intermediary `string` property to bind to `StringInTextBox` and use the `set` `get` methods to validate, but I would have to implement that intermediary `string` to every property in `MyClass` (many properties). I could also make the `UIntConverter` return null to know when to keep the original value, but I would have to make the `UIntProperty` nullable across the code.

I figured I could use the `UIntConverter` and pass the **original** `UintProperty` so the converter can return that value when needed, but I don't know how to pass the `UIntProperty` to the `Param`, I thought `UIntProperty` would be in the same "scope" as for the binding but `Param=UIntProperty` in the code above doesn't work.

**Question**

So, the question is how can I pass `UIntProperty` to `Param` or as the converter parameter? I don't know if I can pass a value to `Param` when the UIntConverter is a `StaticResource`, if possible how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I solve the problem returning `Binding.DoNothing` from `ConvertBack`. Looks like the `ConverterParameter` is not meant to pass values that depend on each object, but to indicate more precisely what kind of conversion is going to be performed, like a type of filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the value "Param=123" is configurable at runtime, but the same for all Items, then it can be set in resources and received in the Converter Parameter using StaticResource.
2. If "Param=123" is configured once when creating a UIntConverter instance, then you can add a property to it and set its value when creating the instance.
3. If "Param=123" is individual for each Items, then you need to use MultiBinding and MultiConverter.

Also, in cases of complex logic, you can consider creating an additional property for the CustomTextBox or Attached Property. But in this case, I see it as redundant. If you need some additional logic, it is better to include it in the StringInTextBox property.

If you provide more clarification on the required functionality and application, then I would try to make an example implementation for you.

**Addition to the answer.**
An example of a Number to String converter that does not change the source property in case of an error converting from a string to the source type.

In case of an error, the special value `Binding.DoNothing` is returned, which tells the binding system not to assign the value returned by the converter.

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace CommonCore.Converters
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(uint), typeof(string))]
    [ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(string))]
    [ValueConversion(typeof(byte), typeof(string))]
    [ValueConversion(typeof(sbyte), typeof(string))]
    [ValueConversion(typeof(short), typeof(string))]
    [ValueConversion(typeof(ushort), typeof(string))]
    [ValueConversion(typeof(long), typeof(string))]
    [ValueConversion(typeof(ulong), typeof(string))]
    [ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(string))]
    [ValueConversion(typeof(float), typeof(string))]
    [ValueConversion(typeof(decimal), typeof(string))]
    public class NumberToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return System.Convert.ToString(value, culture);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string text = (string)value;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
                return System.Convert.ChangeType(0, targetType, culture);
            try
            {
                return System.Convert.ChangeType(value, targetType, culture);
            }
            catch
            {
                return Binding.DoNothing;
            }
        }

        private NumberToStringConverter() { }

        public static NumberToStringConverter Instance { get; } = new();

    }
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(NumberToStringConverter))]
    public class NumberToStringExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return NumberToStringConverter.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The case is the third, `Param` is individual for each item. However, the objective is to edit the `UintInProperty` (source), not the `StringInTextBox` (target), so I have to use `ConvertBack` and pass the `UIntProperty` (or the current item in `ItemsControl`) to know what was the original value, before returning the new one.

Comment: @HansGD, In your example, the value «123» is the same for all Items. But you write that it is individual for everyone. Then please explain where the individual Param values for each Item come from?

Comment: It comes from `UIntProperty`. I know it's the same property used to bind `StringInTextBox`, but I needed it for the `ConvertBack` method where I have to return a `uint` value based on `StringInTextBox`and the current `UIntProperty`, not for the `Convert` method where I can get the value using `Multibinding`. I've seen many questions where they use the `Convert` method and therefore `Multibinding` is the answer. In this case I needed to return a value to edit the source.

Comment: @HansGD If I understand you correctly, then you do not need to know what the value is in the UIntProperty property. You want the converter's "ConvertBack" method to, under some conditions, return a new value for the UIntProperty property, and under other conditions, be able to cancel the converter's action so that the value of the UIntProperty property remains the same. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, canceling the converter's action is one way to solve the problem. The other way is to know `UIntProperty`in each call to `ConvertBack` and return that value under other conditions, which is why I wanted to pass it as `ConverterParameter`. Your solution is also valid.

Comment: @HansGD Read the addition to my answer.

Comment: Great! As a final comment, when `Binding.DoNothing` is returned in `ConvertBack`, the following `Convert` is also cancelled and the string in the custom control remains with the "wrong" value, but that is not a problem.

Comment: «Undoing an invalid value» requires reloading the property. However, a new assignment of the same value to the source VM property does not guarantee that the target TextBox property will be updated. For this task, you need to implement logic at the View level. This can be Custom TextBox, Attached Property, Freezable Proxy and many other options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should revisit the idea of using `DependencyProperty`.

If you have a custom control, you can define any number of dependency properties, and let the custom control have its own responses (via PropertyChanged, CoerceValueCallback, and ValidateValueCallback).

In contrast, the `IValueConverter` is does not allow you to bind to the converter parameter because it is not a `DependencyProperty`. As you build in more complexity (the float logic), you will appreciate having the space to add all the logic you need with a custom control.

So, the typical flow is this:

- Decide how many properties you need to setup (how many one-ways, two-ways, one-way to source)
- Wire-up callbacks so that the control instance is able to respond to property changes.
- Update any readonly (one-way to source) properties)

Coerce value callback is intended for preventing invalid values. For instance, in the case of a slider, you may not set `Value` beyond `Max` or `Min`; so if you update the `Min`, it should coerce `Value` to be in range.

My recommendation is to instead use `PropertyChanged` callbacks to add your logic. Then set the text property as some function of the input (you'd might have two strings, one of them is the value you see after editing, and one while you are editing).
Perhaps you can add a enum type property to indicate which formatting rules you'd like to apply (e.g. UInt formatting, Float formatting, etc.)

Comment: I don't really need to bind to the converter parameter, only to pass the property of `MyClass`. Is there a sintax to do that? Also, I implemented the enum for the formatting types and implemented the callback methods, I use them for cases where I can call a `getLastValidValue`, but when the `uint` is directly bound to the `StringInTextBox`, I figured the converter could help.

Comment: If the parameter is not needed to be bound, you can pass a static (hard-coded) value.  IIRC, for an enum, you can write `{x:Static namespace:Enum.EnumValue}`.
It sounds like the converter can do the job, just be mindful that it is less capable. I view converters as highly-reusable small functions. Depending on your level of reuse you may prefer to wrap this logic in a custom control, or even execute a convert from the custom control also. Lots of possibilities!